# Difference between regexpatch and xpatch

Tags: xpatch

I'm trying to put individual names within my bibliographic entries into brackets, and trying to patch biblatex bibmacros for that, using the facilities of (rege)xpatch.

In particular, I'm trying to patch the bibmacros `name:given-family` and `name:family-given`.

As far as I understood, `regexpatch` offers the same patch commands `xpatch` does, plus some with regex features. And I couldn't grasp from the documentation any change of syntax of the original commands of `xpatch` whithin `regexpatch`. However, the patches which work with `xpatch` return `undefined control sequence` with `regexpatch`. A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}
%\usepackage{regexpatch}

\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% These patches work with xpatch, but not with regexpatch
\xpatchbibmacro{name:given-family}
    {\usebibmacro{name:hook}}
    {\bibopenbracket\usebibmacro{name:hook}}
    {}{}

\xapptobibmacro{name:given-family}
    {\bibclosebracket}
    {}{}

\xpatchbibmacro{name:family-given}
    {\usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}}
    {\bibopenbracket\usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}}
    {}{}

\xpatchbibmacro{name:family-given}
    {\usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}}
    {\bibopenbracket\usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}}
    {}{}

\xapptobibmacro{name:family-given}
    {\bibclosebracket}
    {}{}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Obs: I need `regexpatch` for other patches that actually require the regex facilities, and I'd like to use the original `xpatch` patch commands, if possible, for the sake of code readability.

Comment: A change in macro names that wasn't done at every place it was needed. A maintenance release should arrive soon. In the meantime, use `\xpatchbibmacro*` (changing all appearances should do nothing wrong in the shown cases).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've discovered a hidden feature. `;-)`

This should fix the temporary issue.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

% Fix regexpatch itself
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\exp_args:Nc \xpatchcmd { xpatchbibmacro~code }
 {\xpatch_main:Ncnnnn}
 {\xpatch_main_four:Ncnnnn}
 {}{}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% These patches work with xpatch, but not with regexpatch
\xpatchbibmacro{name:given-family}
    {\usebibmacro{name:hook}}
    {\bibopenbracket\usebibmacro{name:hook}}
    {}{}

\xapptobibmacro{name:given-family}
    {\bibclosebracket}
    {}{}

\xpatchbibmacro{name:family-given}
    {\usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}}
    {\bibopenbracket\usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}}
    {}{}

\xpatchbibmacro{name:family-given}
    {\usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}}
    {\bibopenbracket\usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}}
    {}{}

\xapptobibmacro{name:family-given}
    {\bibclosebracket}
    {}{}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: egreg, once you have your hands on it, I think it is no harm adding that `regexpatch` throws me `Package l3regex Warning: This package is obsolete --- use 'expl3' instead`.

Comment: @gusbrs Yes, that's in the queue.